# How do I call "cpuid" in Linux?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86, cpuid

While writing new code for Windows, I stumbled upon `_cpuinfo()` from the Windows API. As I am mainly dealing with a Linux environment (GCC) I want to have access to the CPUInfo.

I have tried the following:

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
  int a, b;
 
  for (a = 0; a < 5; a++)
  {
    __asm ( "mov %1, %%eax; "            // a into eax
          "cpuid;"
          "mov %%eax, %0;"             // eax into b
          :"=r"(b)                     // output
          :"r"(a)                      // input
          :"%eax","%ebx","%ecx","%edx" // clobbered register
         );
    std::cout << "The CPUID level " << a << " gives EAX= " << b << '\n';
  }
 
  return 0;
}
```

This use assembly but I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Is there any other way to implement CPUInfo without assembly?

Comment: So, this is g++ I guess. And x86? You should say. What is the question in any case? You told us what you are doing, and shown the code. But there's no question.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm running Linux (as in this will be the Linux section to determine the CPU of the computer executing the code). I already have the Windows version/section nailed with the _cpuinfo() function from the Win API. That's my point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan See my updated post, I neglected to add the Compiler errors.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect (what I think) is the intended question. Feel free to roll it back if I'm wrong.

Comment: yet again, a suitable question is downvoted, even when there's no clear answer (there isn't any).

Comment: If my edit is accurate, then let me know and I'll post an answer.

Comment: @Mysticial I know how to implement it for gcc/linux. I'm recieveing compile errors which I do not know how to get rid of, thus make the damn thing build.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan gave a good answer; depending on what you want, it may be easier to read the data from `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Comment: I rolled the question back. Please don't change it like you did. If you want to add your own answer do so. But if you remove all the errors from the question, then the answers look stupid.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I disagree. The title states 'How do I call “cpuid” in Linux?'. The compiler errors where a typo from switching git branches when I tested this code out; ie, not on production code. The answer is not relevant to compiler erros, whereas, it is relevant to 'how do I call cpuinfo from cpuid.h. Sorry, I'm going to edit my question for clarity.

Comment: Your latest edit is different from the one I reverted. This one is better. But I'd still perfer to see the original code with the compiler error because one of the answers now looks very odd. It wasn't @user's fault. They just answered what was there at the time. So I'd sooner see your edit add to the original.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll add the compiler errors in with a note.

Comment: The compile errors surely need to match the code in the question, with the stray ; but maybe it's not worth worrying any more. I suspect I'm annoying you now!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was thinking the same. The post would be cluttered with the code. I think my asm approach is pretty novel, it would surely increase the value of the thread. users's post answers the typo well, not to mention with the code examples; although it currently at the footer. I feel the reader could piece it together , though.

Comment: @TheBlueCat It's not that novel, I've seen this answer on no less than 6 similar questions today while looking for a decent example using the C/C++ that is built in. Rather than various people's adhoc inline assembly answers :-)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since you are compiling with GCC then you can include `cpuid.h` which declares these functions:

```
/* Return highest supported input value for cpuid instruction.  ext can
   be either 0x0 or 0x8000000 to return highest supported value for
   basic or extended cpuid information.  Function returns 0 if cpuid
   is not supported or whatever cpuid returns in eax register.  If sig
   pointer is non-null, then first four bytes of the signature
   (as found in ebx register) are returned in location pointed by sig.  */
unsigned int __get_cpuid_max (unsigned int __ext, unsigned int *__sig)

/* Return cpuid data for requested cpuid level, as found in returned
   eax, ebx, ecx and edx registers.  The function checks if cpuid is
   supported and returns 1 for valid cpuid information or 0 for
   unsupported cpuid level.  All pointers are required to be non-null.  */
int __get_cpuid (unsigned int __level,
    unsigned int *__eax, unsigned int *__ebx,
    unsigned int *__ecx, unsigned int *__edx)
```

You don't need to, and should not, re-implement this functionality.

Comment: +1 Didn't know that header existed. I've always done it with a bit of inline assembly.

Comment: Sure. I managed to get the piece to compile anyway. Notwithstanding, why should I not re-implement this? Besides time-saving?

Comment: @Mysticial This is where my total ignorance of GCC and Linux comes in handy. I had to google for the answer!

Comment: Basic rule of development is to re-use rather than re-implement. Do you write your own `printf`? Or your own `strcmp`? Do you write your own `std::string`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yet another reason why "ignorance" fuels new ideas... ahaha

Comment: Can you provide / include an example usage? And potentially add the return types as well :-P

Comment: @UpAndAdam Fair comment, esp. the return values. I've added these. I also included the comments from the header file that document how to call them. I don't have a suitable compiler at hand so don't want to try my hand at a usage example and get it wrong.

Comment: No problem, much appreciated! I saw those comments as well in the header file and was hoping they made slightly more sense to someone else :-p I'll just have to keep on reading some more

Comment: @UpAndAdam I think you need to read the Intel docs for CPUID to make sense of them.

Comment: I have been trying to of course, there's just lots of it and each reads a little differently than the last :-P Thanks again for the help!

Comment: There's only one official Intel doc.

Comment: hello for level 1, eax=1 my ebx register keeps outputting random values, is there anyway I can check if for a level the register is relevant or not.

Answer (score 8):

```
for (a =0; a < 5; ++a;)
```

There should only be two semicolons there.  You've got three.

This is basic C/C++ syntax; the CPUID is a red herring.

Comment: typo. I fixed it before I posted, for some reason it got back into there. I changed branches on Git, that's probably the reason. But yes, I do know this 'basic syntax'.

Comment: But the errors you posted are caused by this typo.  If you've fixed that and are still having problems, please update the list of errors.

Comment: @user9876: I fixed the question to remove the old error messages; the current code in the question compiles without any warnings. (https://godbolt.org/z/ezzTW7c1a).  It's clunky and only produces the EAX output, but that's why it makes sense to ask for something better.  Anyway, you can finally delete this answer now that it's fully irrelevant to the current question.

Answer (score 1):

@UpAndAdam asked for an example a decade ago... I worked on this today, so here you are :)

```
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <string.h>

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID
// https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h

void print_as_ASCII(unsigned int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char byte = (value >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF; // Extract byte
        printf("%c", byte); // Print as ASCII character
    }
}

void call_cpuid(unsigned int EAX_input, unsigned int *eax, unsigned int *ebx, unsigned int *ecx, unsigned int *edx) {
        unsigned int ret;

        ret = __get_cpuid(EAX_input, eax, ebx, ecx, edx);
        if (ret != 1) {
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "Failed to call CPUID with EAX=%d", EAX_input);
        }
}

int main() {
        unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;

        // EAX=0: Highest Function Parameter and Manufacturer ID
        call_cpuid(0, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);

        printf("CPU Manufacturer ID: ");
        print_as_ASCII(ebx);
        print_as_ASCII(edx);
        print_as_ASCII(ecx);
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

On Linux this call does not require "root" privileges:

```
$ gcc -Wall cpuid-example.c -o cpuid-example && ./cpuid-example
CPU Manufacturer ID: GenuineIntel
```