# Checking for ID flag in RFLAGS using inline assembly in C

Tags: c, x86-64, inline-assembly, cpuid

I have written the following inline assembly to try check for the ID flag. I know that it should be set because I can use the cpuid instruction, however this function returns 0 when I test it.

```c
_Bool /* Checks whether the cpu has the cpuid instruction available */
cpu_has_cpuid(void) {
        uint64_t out;
        asm ("pushfq\n\t"
             "popq %[out]\n\t"
             : [out] "=r" (out)
             :: "memory");
        return out & 0x200000;
}
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong here and can you help me?

If it helps, the value I get without the bitmask is `582`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can and should use GNU C `#include <cpuid.h>` in your own code** instead of GNU C inline asm.  ([How do I call "cpuid" in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266772/how-do-i-call-cpuid-in-linux))  [Example on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vT8fe6) of how it compiles, including the 32-bit mode check for CPUID availability.

---

**x86-64 guarantees the availability of CPUID**; you only need to check for it if your code might run on a 486 or earlier.  But 486 can't run 64-bit code in the first place.

**The actual problem with your code is that it doesn't try to *flip* the ID bit.**  Apparently `0` is normal for its current status. https://wiki.osdev.org/CPUID#Checking_CPUID_availability shows standard detection code (for 32-bit mode Intel-syntax, but easy enough to port) that uses a memory-destination XOR before a popf / pushf / pop reg to see if the setting "took".  (Then it restores the original EFLAGS, which is probably unnecessary.)

For a GNU C inline asm implementation, see GCC's own `cpuid.h` ([github](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/5b32a1817d9aa042698350b04496db6f4fce62d4/gcc/config/i386/cpuid.h#L251)) where it's done inside an `#ifndef __x86_64__` block in `__get_cpuid_max`. It even has dialect-alternatives for AT&T vs. Intel-syntax, so code that uses `#include <cpuid.h>` doesn't break if compiled with `-masm=intel`.

Porting that to x86-64 would let you verify that it actually works, if you're curious.

---

Also, **your push/pop is unsafe** on Linux / Mac (x86-64 System V): **you step on the red-zone**. You need to `add $-128, %rsp` before and `sub $-128, %rsp` after, to avoid your push/pop stepping on the red-zone below the compiler's RSP, where it might be keeping local vars. See [Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm)

`-128` fits in an imm8 but `+128` doesn't, that's why I suggest `add/sub $-128` instead of `sub/add $128`.